# startactivity doesn't work after launch from pendingintent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

I have activity A, B.
A is list of post and B shows a post.
I create notification which start activity B like

```
PendingIntent.getActivity(context, (int) id, intentForB, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

B has no lunchmode and no intent flag at all when start so can be stacked multiple.

This is what i expected when click a notification.

A -> (open noti) -> B

A -> B -> (open noti) -> another B

So far, everything's fine. But when i start app from the pending intent above, problem happens.

If i open notification when application doesn't even exist at background, It shows B standalone. And then when i open another notification, shows nothing.

(open noti) -> B -> (open another noti) -> Another B expected but nothing happened.

If i put FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK to B, it shows B but destroy pervious one. This is not what i want.

So my question is, Why startactivity without flag new_task or clear_top doesn't work when open app from pending intent? How can i make it work?

Comment: What do you want to happen when you open the notification but the app is not running at all?

Answer (score 0):

To get the behaviour you want, you probably need to make B a bit smarter. It needs to know when it has been launched as the "root" `Activity` in a task (the first `Activity`), which would be the case if it was launched from a `Notification` while the app was not running.

If it is launched as the "root" `Activity`, it should redirect to A by clearing the task and launching A and telling A that it should automatically launch B, so that the user sees B. To do this, in `B.onCreate()` do this:

```
super.onCreate(...);
if (isTaskRoot()) {
    // We need to redirect the user to A by restarting the task
    Intent redirectIntent = new Intent(this, A.class);
    redirectIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    // Add extras so that A will automatically launch B
    redirectIntent.putExtra("launchB", true);
    // add any other extras from the original intent
    redirectIntent.putExtras(getIntent());
    startActivity(redirectIntent);
    // We are done, don't do anything else
    finish();
    return;
}
```

Now, in A you need to automatically launch B. To do that, add this code to `A.onCreate()`:

```
super.onCreate(...);
... rest of code from A.onCreate()...
if (getIntent().hasExtra("launchB")) {
    // We should immediately launch B because the user launched B from
    //   from a Notification when the app was not running
    Intent launchIntent = new Intent(this, B.class);
    // Add any extras from the original Intent
    launchIntent.putExtras(getIntent());
    startActivity(launchIntent);
}
```

This will always ensure that A is the root of your task.